# Performing a LIKE on Magento product attribute multiselect

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

Is it possible to do a a LIKE operation on a multiselect attribute on a magento product collection?

For example below I am doing a find in set to locate an exact match:

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('makemodel',
        array('finset' => Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')
                ->getAttribute('makemodel')
                ->getSource()
                ->getOptionId('@Massey Ferguson@#350#')
        )
)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');


if($_productCollection){
    foreach($_productCollection as $product){

        var_dump($product->getData());

    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is get the option ID's for attribute options that contain @Massey Ferguson@ and then find any products with the returned option ID's..

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I came up with a method for doing a like against a multiselect attribute option...

```
$make = $make.'%';
    /** @var $attribute Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute */
    $valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
    ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
    ->addFieldToFilter('value', array ('like' => $make))
    ->addFieldToSelect('option_id')
    ->setStoreFilter(0, false);


$set = array();
foreach($valuesCollection as $option){
    $set[] = $option->getData('option_id');
}

$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('makemodel',
        array('in' => $set
        )
)
->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

This seems to work quite well! If anybody else has a solution that might work better please let me know.